# Sum values of a key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to calculate the total number of disks for each server, the data is stored as follows:

```
config = 
{ 'server1': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 3, 'block' : 300}],
  'server2': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 2200}],
  'server3': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 300}, {'name' : 'data2', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 300}, {'name' : 'data3', 'disks' : 2, 'block' : 1800},  {'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 300}],
  'server4': [{'name' : 'data', 'disks' : 3, 'block' : 300}, {{'name' : 'data2', 'disks' : 8, 'block' : 880}]
}
```

I came up with:

```
for k,v in config.items():
    no_disks = 0
    for l in v:
        no_disks+= l.get('disks')
    print({k:no_disks})
```

Which results in:

```
{'server1': 3}
{'server2': 8}
{'server3': 14}
{'server4': 11}
```

I was trying to do it in a one liner using dict comprehension but can't figure it out, any suggestions for a more elegant solution?

Comment: is pandas an option or do you need it to be a dict comprehension?

Comment: A dictionary comprehension results in *one* dictionary. Apparently you want multiple dictionaries.

Comment: @BjörnB No that's not a requirement, just a thought

Comment: @Lunacy I think Dani Mesejo provided the perfect one-liner with `result = { k : sum(disks(v) for v in vs) for k, vs in config.items()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
from operator import itemgetter

config = {'server1': [{'name': 'data', 'disks': 3, 'block': 300}],
          'server2': [{'name': 'data', 'disks': 8, 'block': 2200}],
          'server3': [{'name': 'data', 'disks': 2, 'block': 300}, {'name': 'data2', 'disks': 2, 'block': 300},
                      {'name': 'data3', 'disks': 2, 'block': 1800}, {'name': 'data', 'disks': 8, 'block': 300}],
          'server4': [{'name': 'data', 'disks': 3, 'block': 300}, {'name': 'data2', 'disks': 8, 'block': 880}]
          }

disks = itemgetter('disks')
result = { k : sum(disks(v) for v in vs) for k, vs in config.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'server1': 3, 'server2': 8, 'server3': 14, 'server4': 11}
```

Or simply access the element directly:

```
result = { k : sum(v['disks'] for v in vs) for k, vs in config.items()}
```

The above dictionary comprehension are equivalent to this for loop:

```
result = {}
for k, vs in config.items():
    result[k] = sum(v['disks'] for v in vs)
```